# ¿Diferencias entre declarar imports de clases y paquetes, o las clases sin hacer import?

Tags: java

por lo que tengo entendido: la ***diferencia entre importar clases concretas o sus paquetes*** está en el ***tiempo de compilación***, menor en el primer caso, aunque esto ***no afectaría al rendimiento de la aplicación***, ¿correcto?

Ahora, ¿qué diferencia hay entre hacer importar la clase o usar esta misma clase sin importar, es decir nombrándola por su paquete y nombre?, ejemplo:

```
miapp.test.Xxx xxx = new miapp.test.Xxx();
```

¿Afecta al tiempo de compilado?

¿Al rendimiento de la aplicación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> la diferencia entre importar clases concretas o sus paquetes está en el tiempo de compilación

Ése no es el problema.

Imagina que estoy en Java 4, y quiero usar `java.util.List` y `java.awt.Button`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

...
   private List miListaDeObjetos = null;
   private Button miBoton = null;
```

Y de repente te da por pasarte a Java 5, y al hacer un cambio cualquiera, te da por recompilar.

Entonces descubres que Java 5 ha añadido una clase `java.awt.List`<sup>1</sup>, por lo cual el compilador no sabe cuál es la clase de `miListaDeObjetos`.

En general, se recomienda importar paquetes para hacer el desarrollo, pero al acabar la programación convertir los imports a clases específicas. Y yo diría que con un IDE moderno, que al escribir el nombre de la clase te permite hacer el import con pulsar una tecla, no hay mucha razón para importar paquetes nunca.

En cuanto a

> ¿qué diferencia hay entre hacer importar la clase o usar esta misma clase sin importar, es decir nombrándola por su paquete y nombre?

La principal diferencia será de rápidez para escribir el programa y legibilidad; normalmente ya sabes que `List` es `java.util.` así que escribirlo te retrasa y al leerlo tienes un montón de "paja".

---

<sup>1</sup>No es un ejemplo real, `java.awt.List` existía desde Java 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ninguna, pero ponete a pensar, es mas sencillo salir de tu casa con lo necesario en la mochila o hacer una mudanza? Ahora traslada eso a tu código. A mi parecer es innecesario y un desperdicio de recursos.

Saludos!!!